# Search for a column name and paste data

Tags: excel, vba

I want to paste the formula into a column by searching the column using its name.

My column name is `Date1`.
I want to find `Date1` in my sheet and paste the following formula:

```
IF(ISBLANK(B5),"""",IF(ISBLANK(O5)=TRUE,""Missing PSD"",TODAY()-O5))
```

This should be calculated until the last row of `Date1` column.

Kindly share any knowledge you have on this, it'd be very helpful.

```
Sub FillFormula()
 Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
 
    Set sh = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = sh.Range("O" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'chosen O:O column, being involved in the formula...
    sh.Range("AC5:AC" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(B5),"""",IF(ISBLANK(O5)=TRUE,""Missing PSD"",TODAY()-O5))"
 
    lastRow2 = sh.Range("R" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    sh.Range("AD5:AD" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(B5),"""",IF(ISBLANK(R5)=TRUE,""Missing RSD"",TODAY()-R5))"
 
End Sub
```

This is the code I am currently using and it works properly but my columns might change so I do not want to use the column character but instead the column name to paste the data into the correct column.

Comment: Does "Date1" already have records? Should the code overwrite the existing formulas? Otherwise, calculating the last row based of this column will be wrong...

Comment: No, Date1 is empty

Comment: So, the last row should be calculated according to another column content. Please, check the code I posted. It calculates last row based on the O:O column, as in my previous answer, since this column is involved in the formula...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It still calculates the last row based on O:O column. If the column "Date1" has already formulas to be overwritten, I can easily adapt the code to use it:

```
Sub FillFormulaByHeader()
 Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, celD As Range
 
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sh = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'Find the header ("Date1"):
    Set celD = sh.Range(sh.Range("A1"), sh.cells(, cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Find("Date1")
    If celD Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Nu such header could be found...": Exit Sub
    
    lastRow = sh.Range("O" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'it can be easily changed for column with Date1 header
    sh.Range(sh.cells(5, celD.Column), sh.cells(lastRow, celD.Column)).Formula = _
                "=IF(ISBLANK(B5),"""",IF(ISBLANK(O5)=TRUE,""Missing PSD"",TODAY()-O5))"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Rohini Baburaj Didn't my code solve your problem? Did you find time to test it?

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let's assume you have Headers in Row1. We now need to find out which column our Date1 Value is in. We can do this by simply looping over the Header Range an check if the Value equals "Date1". Now we can use this information to construct the final Range.

```
Sub FindDate1()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim date1Column as integer
    Dim finalRange As Range

    For Each c In Range("A1:Z1")
        If c.Value = "Date1" Then
            date1Column = c.Column
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c

    If date1Column = 0 Then
        'in case "Date1" was not found
        Exit Sub 
    Else
        Set finalRange = Range(Cells(2, date1Column), Cells(2, date1Column).End(xlDown))
        For Each c In finalRange
            c.Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(B" & c.Row & "),"""",IF(ISBLANK(O" & c.Row & ")=TRUE,""Missing PSD"",TODAY()-O" & c.Row & "))"
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I set the formula to that range? New to VBA so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: you can loop over the established range and set the formula for each row. I updated my Answer